# Rescaling images after posting

Tags: support, feature-request, images

Sometimes my images nicely fit into the rest of the body of the question. Most of the time they are too large. Is it possible to rescale them after posting?

If not can we have that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can scale down images by appending `l` `m` or `s` to the filename, before .extension.

After upload, the image below was named `https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pBS0.png`

[image: original]

Here's the `l` version with URL `https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pBS0l.png`; the images scaled with `l` should not be wider than the allocated horizontal space for the display of question and answers.

[image: large]

And then I changed the URL to `https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pBS0m.png` for the medium version

[image: medium]

and finally here's the small version with URL `https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pBS0s.png`

[image: small]

(From [Please do something to encourage people to scale down their giant heavyweight photos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101439))

Comment: thanks. Unfortunately it blurs more and more and finally swallows the leftmost part. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

I also found this: [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/178818)
which allows quite some control over the image properties:

`<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pBS0.png" width="137" height="42" alt="" title="">`

[image]

`<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pBS0.png" width="666" height="666" alt="" title="">`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It also seems possible to scale the images when you upload them, with this user-script:

https://stackapps.com/questions/3507/thumbnail-uploader